# Want to add search result when search button is clicked

Tags: javascript, search

I am beginner in JavaScript. I am creating a project. Now i want to add a function when search button is clicked then search result display. However with the help of lecture i figure out how to filter when user is typing. But i want to add after typing in Search Bar when user click on search button then it also give the search result on same page same as it giving while typing.

```js
showNotes();
// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  notesObj.push(addTxt.value);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  addTxt.value = "";
  //console.log(notes)
  showNotes();
});
// Function to show elements from localStorage
function showNotes() {
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  let html = "";
  notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
    html += `<div class="noteCard my-2 mx-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"> ${element}</p>
        <button id="${index}"onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
    </div>
</div>`;
  });
  let notesElem = document.getElementById("notes");
  if (notesObj.length != 0) {
    notesElem.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    notesElem.innerHTML = `Nothing to show`;
  }
}

// function to delete a note
function deleteNote(index) {
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  notesObj.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  showNotes();
}

// search code
let search = document.getElementById('searchTxt');
search.addEventListener("input", function(){

    let inputVal = search.value.toLowerCase();
    // console.log('Input event fired!', inputVal);
    let noteCards = document.getElementsByClassName('noteCard');
    Array.from(noteCards).forEach(function(element){
        let cardTxt = element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText;
        if(cardTxt.includes(inputVal)){
            element.style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
        // console.log(cardTxt);
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Notes App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Magic Notes</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="searchTxt" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="btnSearch()">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container my-3">
        <h1>Welcome To Magic Notes</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Add a note</h5>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="addTxt" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">Add Note</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h1>Your Notes</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="notes" class="row container-fluid"> </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```